# Can't animate font-size of child elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have this menu that changes height when you scroll, now that works absolutely great. Only thing is, now I'm trying to animate the font-size so that the font will become smaller as well.

I did some research on child selectors in jQuery (`$('parent > child')`), but when I applied this in my script this didn't work. Anyone has a solution?

[HTML]

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/header.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="content_parent">
            <!-- Header -->
            <div id="header_parent">
                <table class="menuItems">
                    <td>Button</td>
                    <td>Button</td>
                    <td>Button</td>
                    <td>Button</td>
                    <td>Button</td>
                </table>
            </div>

            <!-- Body (homepage) -->
            <div id="body_parent">
                <h1>content-test</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <div id="footer_parent">

        </div>

        <script src="js/animateheader.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[CSS]

```
#content_parent {
    max-width:1250px;
    min-width:750px;
    min-height:100%;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px 2px rgb(180,180,180);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px 2px rgb(180,180,180);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px 2px rgb(180,180,180);
}

#header_parent {
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    max-width:1250px;
    min-width:750px;
    height:60px;
    background-color:rgb(50,50,50);
    box-shadow:-6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0), 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0), 0 6px 4px -2px rgb(180,180,180);
    -webkit-box-shadow:-6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0), 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0), 0 6px 4px -2px rgb(180,180,180);
    -moz-box-shadow:-6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0), 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0), 0 6px 4px -2px rgb(180,180,180);
    border-bottom-left-radius:2px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:2px;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius:2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:2px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:2px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius:2px;
    border-top-left-radius:0;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius:0;
    border-top-right-radius:0;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius:0;
}

#body_parent {
    padding-top:60px;
    max-width:1250px;
    min-width:750px;
    background-color:rgb(245,245,245);
}

table.menuItems {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border:0;
}

.menuItems td {
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    color:rgb(230,230,230);
    font-family:Sansation;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:25px;
}
```

[JS]

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > 0) {
        $('#header_parent').stop().animate({height: "40px"},50);
        $('#body_parent').stop().animate({paddingTop: "40px"},45);
        $('table.menuItems > td').stop().animate({fontSize: "18px"},50);
    }
    else {
        $('#header_parent').stop().animate({height: "60px"},50);
        $('#body_parent').stop().animate({paddingTop: "60px"},45);
        $('table.menuItems > td').stop().animate({fontSize: "25px"},50);
    }
});
```

Just for clearance, the jQuery lines with fontSize in it are the ones not functioning the way I want.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52czbb73/)

Comment: @DavidLaberge Yeah, I had to wait 5 mins, I guess you answer too quickly :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an updated version of the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/52czbb73/1/

Your selector was wrong

```
$('table.menuItems > tbody > tr > td').stop().animate({fontSize: "18px"},50);
```

I took the liberty to add the `tr` tag in your table.

```
        <div id="header_parent">
            <table class="menuItems">
                <tr>
                <td>Button</td>
                <td>Button</td>
                <td>Button</td>
                <td>Button</td>
                <td>Button</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

By the way in google chrome you can get the CSS path from the Developer Tools by right clicking the element you want to target then select `CSS path` that copies the CSS path to the clipboard. Then paste it in your code.

Comment: Ah thanks I deleted the `tr` tag a while ago but forgot about it ... What is the purpose of `tbody` if I may ask?

Comment: @YSbakker `tbody` is the element that wraps the body of the table. It is always required. If you don't include it in your HTML markup the browser will generally add it for you.

Comment: HTML table have three possible section `thead`, `tbody`, `tfooter`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That explains why it wasn't stated on the jQuery website. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrng selector, you can select your `td`s like this:

```
$('table.menuItems td').stop().animate({fontSize: "25px"},50);
```

and

```
$('table.menuItems td').stop().animate({fontSize: "18px"},50);
```

Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/52czbb73/2/

Comment: Thanks for your effort, however I think David's answer is more specified. But this works as well so +1 for the effort ;)